# Problems running glibc 2.14 on RHEL6

Tags: rhel, android, glibc

I am trying to run the latest version of the Android SDK on an RHEL6 box. I am getting errors that I need GLIBC 2.14. So I installed GLIBC 2.14 in /opt/glibc-2.14.

I have set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib`. I can now run the Android SDK tool without getting prompted that GLIBC 2.14 is not installed. But when I try to run the Gradle build to build the Android APK it just hangs.

If I remove the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` the Gradle job runs and fails that GLIBC 2.14 is not installed. I also have the same hanging issue on running a command such as `java --version`, when `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to GLIBC 2.14.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You'd need to install all the required libraries and programs locally which will quickly become a total mess.  It would be much better to run it on a more up-to-date OS.

Answer (score -1):

We have the same issue using gradle via jenkins build-pipeline.

I manually compiled glibc 2.14 under /opt/glibc-2.14.
If I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH the android sdk works fine, but calling a gradle build fails with an "futex" error message (seen on strace).

There is no output, even when running gradle with the stacktrace option.

The only way I was getting gradle to run was to install the following RPM's from redsleeve.org:

```
wget http://ftp.redsleeve.org/pub/steam/glibc-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget http://ftp.redsleeve.org/pub/steam/glibc-common-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget http://ftp.redsleeve.org/pub/steam/glibc-devel-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget http://ftp.redsleeve.org/pub/steam/glibc-headers-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh glibc-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm glibc-common-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm glibc-devel-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm glibc-headers-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

After the installation of the updated glibc-packages the gradle build was running fine on a CentOS 6.9 (x64) box.

This is good for a testing environment, but in case of system-updates this could break your whole update procedure.
I'm trying to find a better way using the manually compiled version.

~Cheers